# Spring Security 5.x, WebFlux, Reactive, How to store Authentication in ReactiveSecurityContextHolder

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux, reactive

I am building a OAuth2 authorization server using Spring Boot 2.3.1 and WebFlux. I am running into a issue. After successfully authenticating, the `Authorization` object is missing from the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` object.

I have an implementation of `ServerSecurityContextRepository` which implements the `load` method as below.

@Override
public Mono load(ServerWebExchange swe) {

```
return swe.getSession().map(WebSession::getAttributes).flatMap((attrs) -> {
  ServerHttpRequest request = swe.getRequest();
  String authHeader = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

  if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ") && authHeader.contains(" ")) {
    // Split the auth header at space and the second token is the authToken.
    String authToken = authHeader.split(" ")[1];

    try {

// Some code removed here.
      Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, authToken);
      SecurityContext sc = (SecurityContext)attrs.get(VarahamihirConstants.SECURITY_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
      if (sc == null) {
        sc = new SecurityContextImpl(auth);
        save(swe, sc);
      }
      final SecurityContext context = sc;
      return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map((authentication) -> {
        context.setAuthentication(authentication);
        return context;
      });
    } catch (ParseException|JOSEException|BadJOSEException e) {
      return Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException("The auth token is invalid."));
    }
  } else {
    return Mono.empty();
  }
});

}
```

I also have an implementation of `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` which implements `authenticate` method.

```
public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
String authToken = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
try {
  Principal principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
  if (!jwtUtil.validateToken(principal.getAuthToken())) {
    return Mono.empty();
  }
// Some code removed.
                Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal,
                        authToken,
                        actualAuthorities);
                return Mono.just(auth);
              })
      return Mono.just(auth);
  }
  //SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  return Mono.error(e);
}
return Mono.error(new UnauthorizedException("Unreachable place."));
```

}

After this, the code works fine in handling the authentication flow but the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` does not contain any context. Also because of that any of the `PrePost` annotations can't be used.

I intuitively understand, somewhere I have to save the context into context holder but where?

Comment: Could you provide your AuthenticationWebFilter config? Usually, is there where the security context is saved

Comment: I have just added the default one just at `AUTHORIZATION`. Do I need to add my own implementation?  `  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                                          ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer) {
    return http.addFilterAt(new AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager),
            SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .csrf().disable()
            .build();
  }
` I just checked, it doesn't seem to be getting called though.

Comment: If you didn't set nothing, by default Spring Security use `NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository` as repository inside `AuthenticationWebFilter` so if you want to use your own repository use the setter method of `AuthenticationWebFilter` class and set yours.